# In include file: 'math.h' file is not found. QT Creator

Tags: c++, qt, vtk

I am using QT to display PCD file by VTK, I am facing the problem such like;
In included file: 'math.h' file not found

I have already checked the 'edit system environment variable', .pro file's INCLUDE file etc. etc.  that's fine.

can anyone encounter such issue? please response, thanks indeed.

Comment: do you mean `cmath` ? `math.h` is a C header

Comment: i am using C++.

Answer (score 1):

This problem has been solved by my colleague's suggestion;

```
Visual Studio Installer > Game Development with C++ > Optional ;
```

Install different "Window 10 SDK(10.0.22000.0) and so on
after that simple test the 'hello world' program.

Good luck indeed for all this queries

Answer (score 0):

You should use [CMake to configure your project](https://vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Tutorials/CMakeListsFile), not QMake. If you insist on using QMake, compile a hello world example using CMake. Then take include paths etc from it and add it to your QMake project.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the absolute path of your math.h file to check that Qt has access to it ( ie: #include "C:\Qt\Tools\mingw530_32\i686-w64-mingw32\include\math.h" ) and if it works, then check Qt INC dirs.